# Exception handling in Seam, Transaction is not active

Tags: java, exception, jboss, transactions, seam

I'm having a hard time understanding how to properly catch an exception in Jboss Seam 2.2.

In terms of plan Java, a simple try/catch would suffice, but in Seam, with all the 'magic' that goes on behind the scenes (interceptors etc), things are not working how I would expect.

Here's an example: My page calls an action #{errorCaller.callError}

```
@Name("errorCaller")
public class ErrorCaller {

    @In(create=true)
    private ErrorClass errorClass;

    @In
    private Session hibernateReadWriteSession;

    public void callError() {
        System.out.println("MAKE AN ERROR!");
        try {
            errorClass.causeError();
        } catch(Exception e) {
            System.out.println("SAFELY CAUGHT!");
        }
        System.out.println("EVERYTHING IS OK, RIGHT?");

        String hql = "from MyTable";
        Query query = hibernateReadWriteSession.createQuery(hql);
        query.list();       

        System.out.println("NOPE! THE TRANSACTION IS NOT ACTIVE!");
    }

}

@Name("errorClass")
public class ErrorClass {

    public void causeError() {
        String nullString = null;
        nullString.equals(null);
    }

}
```

So if this was plan old Java, then the exception would have been handled, but with Seam, the query cannot be executed, because the transaction is not active.

```
10:13:48,546 INFO  [STDOUT] MAKE AN ERROR!
10:13:48,547 INFO  [STDOUT] SAFELY CAUGHT!
10:13:48,547 INFO  [STDOUT] EVERYTHING IS OK, RIGHT?
10:13:48,548 WARN  [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] SQL Error: 0, SQLState: null
10:13:48,548 ERROR [org.hibernate.util.JDBCExceptionReporter] Transaction is not active:  tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff7f000101:126a:52986353:a6 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >; - nested throwable: (javax.resource.ResourceException: Transaction is not active: tx=TransactionImple < ac, BasicAction: 0:ffff7f000101:126a:52986353:a6 status: ActionStatus.ABORT_ONLY >)
10:13:48,549 SEVERE [javax.enterprise.resource.webcontainer.jsf.application] org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection: javax.faces.el.EvaluationException: org.hibernate.exception.GenericJDBCException: Cannot open connection
```

If I handle the NullPointerException where it occurs inside errorClass.causeError(), Seam is quite happy to perform the query.

How should a scenario like this be dealt with?

Do I really need to ensure that all exceptions are handled inside the method itself?

What if I need a custom 'throws MySpecialException' on a method signature?

Thanks in advance! :)

Comment: That is not seam-specific though, you can get the same problems with any other ORM-enabled logic. When a persistence related action blows up, the transaction will be rolled back. If you then attempt to do persistence related stuff in the error handling that follows, things won't go right unless you manually create an isolated transaction for that error handling logic.

Comment: Is that still the case even when the exception was thrown and caught before any ORM-logic has begun? In my example the HQL is being run outside of the catch. Thanks!